# Need help - temporary 'reinforcement' for bending wood floorboard

Tags: wood, floor, board

I am going to have someone come out to check out this floorboard (and the rest of the floors), but in the meantime I'm super anxious I might step on this board and break it.

The issue: I live in a house from 1920. Previous update the owners put carpet over the original floors - original floors from that era are wood floors with no subfloor. That was typical of that era of construction. I rent the house and owners are out of the country. I noticed the past few months a few boards have gotten squeakier, but one in particular right over the threshold to my bedroom has also started sinking a smidge when I step on it.

I'm finding someone to come look at it, but in the meantime before they can come out I'm paranoid I will 'fall through'. Is it reasonable to buy a piece of plywood to put over the area to spread out the weight over multiple boards? or should I put masking tape down to make sure I don't step on that particular area? Unfortunately, it's how I access my bed so it's not easy to avoid.

I appreciate the advice.

Comment: With plywood or similar the edges, you might want to have a slope.  A 1/2 inch rise enough to hit with a toe or trip on if not paying attention.  You will expect a flat floor for the first week/s.

Comment: A steel plate would be thinner yet still strong enough at 1/8" or so. Put a rug on top of it for appearance and not as cold on the feet.

Comment: Put a bucket of sand on the floorboard.  Then you won't step on it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your direct question, yes, you can buy a bit of plywood (home depot/ any big box will sell 2'x2' chunks; 1/2" will be sufficient) to simply drop over the questionable floorboard.

I wouldn't use tape, as it's not a great reminder in the dark, and if you leave it on too long, you could have sticky goo to deal with.